# Groups of order the power of a prime are nilpotent

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that every p-group is nilpotent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140381/prove-that-every-p-group-is-nilpotent)

How can I prove that groups with order a power of a prime are nilpotent?

Comment: Kind of related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140692/a-simpler-version-of-the-burnsides-theorem). Basically: You show that the group has non-trivial centre, then pass to the quotient G/Z(G).

Comment: The post this was linked to did not actually contain a proof (the argument proposed by the OP was flawed); I've added a correct proof, using the lower central series, to my answer there. Note, however, that there are many ways of defining "nilpotent" (upper central series, lower central series, and a few others); you'll want to specify exactly what is your definition or what conditions you know are equivalent to nilpotency for this question to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link for the proof:

- http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Prime_power_order_implies_nilpotent